# How do I bind Function keys to Buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, key-bindings

I want to bind a function key to menu button like when i click **F5** program ends, I used `root.bind("<Function-5>", quit)` but its wrong. Is there any other way of doing it, such that I can use commands when ever I click on **F5** ?

Comment: Try using `root.bind("<F5>", ...)`.

Comment: Its working, I was ignoring capital letters too, thanks !

Comment: Not 100% sure but [these](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html) should be all of the possible key bindings.

Comment: @TheLizzard I had added your comment in answer, and provided one more link that may help OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from @TheLizzard comment,
You should use this to bind `F5` in root :

```
root.bind("<F5>",quit)
```

You can learn about these for from [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-event-binding) and [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html)